# Guidewire profiler .gwprof file analyser

Tags: performance-testing, monitoring, loadrunner, guidewire

Is there any way to analyse .gwprof file (got it from guidewire profiler).

Background- I am performance testing guidewire application, and using guidewire profiler for monitoring the batch process and REST API's. I need to get the statistics from .gwprof file but unable to open that.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Analysis documentation for importing datapoint data from third party sources and what the file format needs to be for the import to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have gathered profiler data in .gwprof file, you can open it from server tools (Shift + Alt + T):

*Guidewire Profiler -> Profiler Analysis -> Saved File*

There you can import saved file to analyse, in opposition to working with data gathered on this particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the gwprof file in any version of IntelliJ Idea or Guidewire Studio if you have the IntelliJ Profiler plugin installed. This plugin provides additional capabilities like searching by stack or frame, advanced sorting and expanding frames to get better visibility, search by keyword or SQL query/table name. It also has the auto-analysis capability to detect common anti-patterns.

The plugin zip is available on the Guidewire Marketplace and can be downloaded for free with a partner/customer account. You can go to the [Guidewire Marketplace](https://marketplace.guidewire.com/) and search for **"Profile Analysis Tool for Guidewire Applications"** or contact your Guidewire representative.